# Float property act differently on two different container

Tags: html, css, css-float

In the example below we have two `div` container that have at least one floating element, but only in `nav` container floating element cause `nav` background to disappear as expected due to change in container height. I corrected this by using overflow property.
But why doesn't floating h2 element inside `content div` act the same and doesn't cause its parent container background to disappear?

```css
h2 {
  background: green;
  float: right;
  width: 275px;
  font-size: 130%;
  font-style: italic;
  font-family: Georgia, Times, serif;
  margin: 10px 10px 0px 10px;
  padding: 30px;
  border-top: 1px solid #665544;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #665544;
}

.content {
  background: blue;
}

.nav {
  background: yellow;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li {
  float: left;
  background: pink;
  width: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li style="margin-left:-40px;">1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li style="float:right; border-left: solid 5px red; margin-right: 0px">5</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <h1>The Evolution of the Bicycle</h1>
  <h2>"Life is like riding a bicycle. To keep your balance you must keep moving." Albert Einstein</h2>
  <p>In 1817 Baron von Drais invented a walking machine that would help him get around the royal In 1817 Baron von Drais invented a walking machine that would help him get around the royal gardens faster: two same-size in-line wheels, the front one steerable,
    mounted in a frameIn 1817 Baron von Drais invented a walking machine that would help him get around the royal gardens faster: two same-size in-line wheels, the front one steerable, mounted in a frame gardens faster: two same-size in-line wheels, the
    front one steerable, mounted in a frame ... </p>
</div>
```

Comment: I can see yellow background for `nav`, blue for `content` andf green background for `<h2>`. What are you expecting?

Comment: I expect blue background of  `content` container disappear (don't see blue background) because `content` container has `h2` element that floated to the right.
Doesn't floating elements cause its parent container height to be zero pixel and then background of that container disappear?

Comment: Well `<h2>` is not the only child of `content`. It will obtain height from it's other children? What about the `<h1>` and `<p>` that is not floated?

Comment: But if I delete other elements in `content` container such as `<h1>` and `<p>` that there will be nothing other that floated element, I still see blue background. and then even if I change `<h2>` to another  `<div>` the blue background still remain and I can see it.

Comment: "the blue background still remain and I can see it" - nope. Once you delete those elements it's gone. I just tested the snippet to make sure.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/uHmR1Ln.png

here it is.

Comment: [It does not](https://jsfiddle.net/7enm2hag/). That image is not the output of the code you shared in question. You probably need a reset of browsers default styles `* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229984/discussion-between-vahid-kamyab-and-t-j).